# How can I speed up my minimum-depth-of-binary-tree function?

Tags: c, optimization, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to improve my code efficiency and i'm trying to solve the minimum depth tree problem using recursion method but i'm not sure if this is the best way to approach the problem. I got faster than 6% of coders on LeetCode but can't improve it more than that.

```
int minDepth(struct TreeNode* root) {

    if(root == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL){
        return 1;
    }
    if(!root->left){
        return minDepth(root->right) + 1;
    }
    if(!root->right){
        return minDepth(root->left)+1;
    }
    if(minDepth(root->right) > minDepth(root->left)){
        return minDepth(root->left) + 1;
    }else{
        return minDepth(root->right) + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(minDepth(root->right) > minDepth(root->left)){
        return minDepth(root->left) + 1;` - you are calling the same function with the same parameter *twice*. See the optimization here?

Comment: I see that but how would i compare the returns of them?

Comment: By using variables?

Comment: ofc, just put in variables the result of `minDepth(root->right)` and `minDepth(root->left)` then return the right variable value

Comment: this is also nothing but the execution can check 2 times if left or right is null, you can also improve that

Comment: Anyway, this is not a tail recursion, meaning it is not going to be converted to loop. So I would imagine an iterative solution to be faster. But this is something to be profiled.

Comment: Consider traversing the tree breadth-first instead of a depth-first.  Done properly, the BF approach should not be worse than the DF for any case, and for some cases it should be better.

Comment: There may also be tricks you can play with the data structure to customize it for the problem.  For example, add a member in which you can record the node's current depth, and add an extra pointer with which to form nodes into a BF queue without doing any extra allocation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Just to be curiuos, i always use a queue for breadth first searche, and since he is programming in C, I think he would have to implement a queue first or is there another approach?

Comment: And consider replacing recursion with iteration.

Comment: @Osiris, yes, you need a queue of some sort for BFS.  But it doesn't necessarily need to be a separate data structure.

Comment: Also note. Once found one depth, there is no reason to descend anything deeper than that. You might want to write a helper function receiving extra parameters.

Comment: @EugeneSh. But i think that only applies for a BFS, if you make a recursive DFS you can't stop after finding one leaf node.

Comment: @Osiris If we have finished to traverse a left subtree and found it's minimum depth, we can pass that value to the traversal of the right subtree, so it will know when to stop.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, then we would need an additional parameter to pass it, but I don't doubt that would be a better approach. But with a DFS we can't stop at the point we found a leaf, but i see that i misunderstood your phrasing of "go any deeper", you are completly right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

close solution with previous but with less comparison to 0 (compared to Osiris) or recursive calls (compared to lvella)

```
int minDepth(struct TreeNode* root) {
  if (root == NULL){
    return 0;
  }

  if(root->left == NULL) {
    return (root->right == NULL) ? 1 : minDepth(root->right) + 1;
  }

  if(root->right == NULL) {
    return minDepth(root->left) + 1;
  }

  int r = minDepth(root->right);
  int l = minDepth(root->left);

  return ((r > l) ? l : r) + 1;
}
```

of course `if (root == NULL)` is useful only for the first call, but to remove it it is needed to have 2 functions

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments you can spare the multiple calls if you save the return value:

```
int minDepth(struct TreeNode* root) {

    if(root == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL){
        return 1;
    }

    int minDepth_left = minDepth(root->left);
    int minDepth_right = minDepth(root->right);

    if(!root->left){
        return minDepth_right+1;
    }
    if(!root->right){
        return minDepth_left+1;
    }
    if(minDepth_right > minDepth_left){
        return minDepth_left + 1;
    }else{
        return minDepth_right + 1;
    }
}
```

When I tested it it gave me a runtime of 4ms on Leetcode.